# Can I map a drive letter to an Azure Storage fileshare from my Azure App Service (not VM)

Tags: ms-access, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service, fileshare

I have an Azure App Service and an Azure Storage Account. I know there is a server/vm behind the app service, but I have not explicitly started a machine.

I'm trying to import data from an access database which will be regularly uploaded to a fileshare in my storage account. I'd like to use an Azure WebJob to do the work in the background.

I'm trying to use DAO to read the data:

```
string path = @"\\server\share\folder\datbase.mdb";
DBEngine dbe = new DBEngine();
Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(path);
DAO.Recordset rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from ...");
```

This works when I run it locally, but when I try to run it in my web job accessing a fileshare in my storage account, it is not finding the file. I assume this is because DBEngine knows nothing of Azure and Azure account names and security keys, doesn't send them and Azure Storage doesn't respond.

So what I'd like to try is to see if I can map an Azure Storage Fileshare onto the server underlying my App Service. I've tried a number of different things, but have received variations of "Access Denied" each time. I have tried:

- Running net use T: \name.file.core.windows.net\azurefileshare
  /u:name key from the App Service consoles in the Azure Portal
- Running
  net use from a process within my webjob
- Invoking WNetAddConnection2
  from within my webjob

Looks like the server is locked down tight. Does anyone have any ideas on how I might be able to map the fileshare onto the underlying server?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Azure web app runs in [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). we could not map an Azure file share to Azure web app. So Azure file storage is a good place if you choose Azure web app. From my experience, there are below workarounds for you. Hope this could give you some tips.

1) Use Azure file storage, but choose Azure VM or Cloud service as host service.

2) Still choose Azure web app as host service, but include the access db in the solution and upload to Azure web app.

3) Choose SQL Azure as database instead. Here is [the article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313051(v=sql.110).aspx) that could help us to migrate the access database to SQL Azure

Comment: Hi Jambor, thanks for your suggestions. 1) is an option, I'm just trying to see if there is a way to avoid having a VM in addition to my App Service. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, as Jambor rightly says, the App Service VM is locked down tight.

However, it turns out that the App Service VM comes with some local temporary storage for the use of the various components running on the VM.

This is at D:\local\Temp\ and can be written to by a web job.

Interestingly, this is a logical folder on a different share/drive from D:\local and the size of this additional storage is dependent on the App Service's scale.